# Angular Node Problems

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, command-line-interface

Trying to learn angular recently, but I am stuck in an error of angular. So here it is.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04, installed node latest version via nvm.
But I have "two" nodes in Ubuntu,[default] nodejs which is  v8 now, and the node v13.
When I try to create angular project with `ng new my-first-project` it runs good, but it keeps warning of some deprecated dependencies for example core-js. I upgraded core-js to the latest(forced using sudo). But the deprecation warning did not disappear, I thought to use `sudo ng new my-first-project` but this time it brings me error

```
You are running version v8.10.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.
```

How can I change angular's using nodejs -> node?

Answer (score 0):

You have two Node.js versions installed with nvm, v8 and v13. It seems that Node.js v8 is active, you can check this with `node --version` command line command. If the version is really v8 you have to change it with nvm to v13 using  `nvm use 13.{x.x}` command. The {x.x} should be the concrete installed version. If you don't know the installed versions by heart you can check them with `nvm list` command line command.

If you change the active Node.js version to v13 with nvm it will be used by Angular CLI and you won't get the above mentioned error.

Comment: @Hrant Nurijanyan: Any feedback?